# How to get object from json array in alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview, alamofire

I'm using `SwiftyJSON` for parse JSON ,
 After parse json my collectionview not load data,
why this dosen't work ?

My request

```
  Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{ response in
                let json = JSON(rawValue: response.result.value!)

                do {
                    //create json object from data

                    let Packages = json!["packagesData"].array
                    for package in Packages! {
                        let titles = (package["title"]) as! String
                        self.tts.append(titles)
               }
                    print(self.tts)



                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

       }
```

My collectionView

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCellCollectionViewCell

                cell.tit.text = tts[indexPath.row] as? String

                return cell

    }
```

Comment: I think you should edit your question. Be spesific. What do you want and what kinda you get error?

Comment: just add this `self.collectionView.reloadData()` under `for loop`

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the collection

```
for package in Packages! {
   let titles = (package["title"]) as! String
   self.tts.append(titles)
}
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```